# Qual a diferença entre Tautologia, Contradições e Contingências?

Tags: matemática, lógica

Quem estuda a Matemática ou desenvolve algoritmos deve saber que a Lógica Matemática é essencial para diversas áreas do conhecimento, ex: na computação(programação), então gostaria de saber, qual a diferença entre Tautologia, Contradições e Contingências?

Answer (score 9):

**Tautologia**

> Tautologia é uma proposição cujo valor lógico é sempre verdadeiro.

Exemplo :

A proposição p ∨ (~p) é uma tautologia, pois o seu valor lógico é sempre V, conforme a tabela-verdade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A proposição (p Λ q) → (p → q) é uma tautologia, pois a última coluna da tabela-verdade só possui V.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Contradição**

> Contradição é uma proposição cujo valor lógico é sempre falso.

A proposição p Λ (~p) é contraválida,pois os resultados com verdadeiro e falso sempre dão falso no final da coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A proposição ~(p ν q) Λ (p Λ q) é contraválida, pois a última coluna da tabela-verdade só possui F.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Contingência**

> Quando uma proposição não é tautológica nem contraválida, a chamamos de contingência ou proposição contingente ou proposição indeterminada.

**Observações**

> Observe que como uma tautologia é sempre Verdadeira, sua negação sempre assumirá o valor lógico da Falsidade, resultando assim em uma contradição.
>
> Sobre a palavra tautologia :
>
> 1.Vício de linguagem que consiste em dizer, por formas diversas, sempre a
> mesma coisa:
> “A gramática usual é uma série de círculos viciosos, uma tautologia infinita.”
> (João Ribeiro, Cartas Devolvidas, p. 45.)

E caso quiser uma explicação mais complexa sobre estes assuntos,sugiro ler [este artigo](https://matematicauniban.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/cap-3-tautologias-contradicoes-e-contingencias.pdf).

**Conclusão**

> A tautologia,contradição e contingência ,são importantes conceitos para prosseguirmos no estudo da lógica matemática e computacional.É interessante que ao começo de se querer aprender a arte de programar,seja ensinado estas partes lógicas pois um programador bom necessita de lógica.

Comment: *(p Λ q) Λ (p Λ q)* não é contradição. E a tabela verdade que se segue na figura abaixo é do *p Λ (~p)* (que de fato é uma contradição) e não do *(p Λ q) Λ (p Λ q)*.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Já arrumei,obrigado por ter corrigido o erro.

Comment: @PauloOliveira Sim eu sei,mas gosto de corrigir para não ocorrer nenhuma confusão na resposta :)