# O que é e para que serve uma "tabela verdade"?

Tags: lógica, álgebra-booleana, tabela-verdade

Bem, a pergunta é justamente esta, quero saber o que é e para que serve uma tabela verdade.

Não quero saber todos os detalhes, só uma definição básica e um exemplo.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre Tautologia, Contradições e Contingências?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136968/91)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

É como se fosse uma tabela de tabuada, mas em outro contexto.

Ela demonstra os resultados de operações de álgebra booleana. Por ter só dois valores de entrada e dois resultados possíveis sempre é muito fácil demonstrar em uma tabela tudo  oque pode ocorrer com uma expressão booleana.

A expressão booleana é aquela que trabalha com operandos que só permitem 0 ou 1.

Pode-se criar a tabela para qualquer expressão booleana, mas já existem tabelas prontas para os operados lógicos básicos e eventualmente algum composto básico.

Principais operadores:

Conjunção

[image: Conjunção]

Disjunção

[image: Disjunção]

Implicação

[image: Implicação]

Igualdade

[image: Igualdade]

Disjunção exclusiva

[image: Disjunção exclusiva]

Não conjunção

[image: Não conjunção]

Não disjunção

[image: Não disjunção]

[image: Operadores tabela verdade]

```
T = true, F = false
∧ = AND (conjunção)
∨ = OR (disjunção)
∨ = XOR (ou exclusivo)
∧ = XNOR (não ou exclusivo)
→ = condicional "if-then"
← = condicional "(then)-if"
⟺ = bicondicional "if-and-only-if" igual ao XNOR
```

[image: Tabela verdade]

[Veja Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 9):

Primeiro, vamos começar com uma pergunta mais simples: O que é uma tabuada?

Uma tabuada é uma tábua que lista vários valores possíveis de uma conta a ser realizada. Por exemplo, na tabuada do 3, temos ***3 × 0 = 0***, ***3 × 1 = 3***, ***3 × 2 = 6***, ***3 × 3 = 9***... Observe que o formato é sempre ***3 × a = n***, onde ***a*** é um valor de entrada e ***n*** é um valor de saída.

Já em uma tabuada completa daquela que se aprende nas escolas, temos todos os valores de ***a × b = n***, onde ***a*** e ***b*** variam de 0 a 10 e ***n*** é a saída. Neste caso, temos duas entradas.

Você pode montar tabelas desse tipo para qualquer função, operador ou expressão matemática. Por exemplo, eis a tabela da função ***f(x) = x² + 2***:

```
  x | f(x)
----+------
  0 |  2
  1 |  3
  2 |  6
  3 | 11
  4 | 18
  5 | 27
  6 | 38
 ...
```

Agora, imagine que ao invés de números, você utilize valores booleanos para montar essas tabelas. Os valores de entrada e de saída agora são apenas conjuntos de verdadeiro e falso. Por exemplo, eis a tabela da função ***f(x) = NÃO x***:

```
 x | f(x)
---+-----
 V | F
 F | V
```

Essa tabela para funções ou operadores booleanos **é a tabela-verdade**. É o equivalente em lógica booleana para as tabelas de tabuadas das operações matemáticas.

Há uma coisa interessante a se notar aqui. As tabelas de tabuadas matemáticas são geralmente infinitas. Isso ocorre porque os possíveis valores de entrada também são infinitos. Por exemplo, numa tabela de tabuada do 3 (***3 × a = n***), há infinitos possíveis valores para ***a***, e portanto, infinitas linhas na tabela. Já no caso das tabelas verdade, como cada variável só pode ter um número finito de valores (e esse número é 2 - verdadeiro ou falso), então o tamanho da tabela é finito.

Os operadores básicos da lógica booleana são o NÃO (denotador pelo símbolo `¬`), o OU (denotado por `∨`) e o E (denotado por `∧`). Outros operadores que você vai encontrar também são o OU-EXCLUSIVO (também chamado de XOR, denotado por `⊻`), a EQUIVALÊNCIA (denotado por `↔`) e a IMPLICAÇÃO (denotado por `→`). Estas são as tabelas-verdade deles:

```
 x | ¬x
---+----
 V | F
 F | V
```

```
 x | y | x ∧ y
---+---+-------
 V | V | V
 V | F | F
 F | V | F
 F | F | F
```

```
 x | y | x ∨ y
---+---+-------
 V | V | V
 V | F | V
 F | V | V
 F | F | F
```

```
 x | y | x ⊻ y
---+---+-------
 V | V | F
 V | F | V
 F | V | V
 F | F | F
```

```
 x | y | x ↔ y
---+---+-------
 V | V | V
 V | F | F
 F | V | F
 F | F | V
```

```
 x | y | x → y
---+---+-------
 V | V | V
 V | F | F
 F | V | V
 F | F | V
```

Podemos ver que todas as tabelas verdade acima (exceto a do NÃO) têm as mesmas variáveis como entrada. Podemos construir então uma tabela assim:

```
 x | y | x ∧ y | x ∨ y | x ⊻ y | x ↔ y | x → y
---+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
 V | V | V     | V     | F     | V     | V
 V | F | F     | V     | V     | F     | F
 F | V | F     | V     | V     | F     | V
 F | F | F     | F     | F     | V     | V
```

Isso daí na verdade são 5 tabelas-verdades colocadas lado a lado, pois as entradas são as mesmas. Isso serve para poder comparar os diferentes valores de saída quando os valores de entrada são os mesmos, além de ficar mais simples de se olhar.

Um exemplo de uma tabela-verdade mais complicadinha é a de uma função ***f(x, y, z) = (x ∧ y) ∨ ¬z***:

```
 x | y | z | f(x, y, z)
---+---+---+------------
 V | V | V | V
 V | F | V | F
 F | V | V | F
 F | F | V | F
 V | V | F | V
 V | F | F | V
 F | V | F | V
 F | F | F | V
```

Quanto ao tamanho da tabela-verdade, podemos ver que a tabela lista em cada linha, uma possível combinação de valores de entrada. Sabendo que cada variável têm dois possíveis valores, então uma tabela-verdade de uma função/operador/expressão booleana de ***n*** variáveis precisará de ***2<sup>n</sup>*** linhas da tabela para listar todas as combinações de entrada possíveis.

Uma forma de se comparar se duas ou mais funções/operadores/expressões são equivalentes é comparando as tabelas-verdade. Por exemplo, vamos comparar as expressões ***x → y***, ***y ∨ ¬x*** e ***y → x***:

```
 x | y | x → y | y ∨ ¬x | y → x
---+---+-------+--------+-------
 V | V | V     | V      | V
 V | F | F     | F      | V
 F | V | V     | V      | F
 F | F | V     | V      | V
```

Olhando para essas tabelas, podemos concluir que a expressão ***x → y*** produz o mesmo resultado que ***y ∨ ¬x***, pois as tabelas-verdades delas são iguais. Se são iguais então são expressões equivalentes (tal como ***c + c*** é equivalente a ***2 × c*** ou como ***c × c*** é equivalente a ***c<sup>2</sup>***). Entretanto, elas são diferentes que ***y → x***.

Answer (score 8):

## Definição

Uma tabela de verdade é uma representação tabular de todas as combinações de valores para entradas e suas saídas correspondentes. É uma tabela matemática que mostra todos os resultados possíveis que ocorrerão de todos os cenários possíveis que são considerados factuais, daí o nome. As tabelas de verdade geralmente são usadas para problemas de lógica como na álgebra booleana e nos circuitos eletrônicos.

**Exemplo de uso**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Para testar sentenças lógicas como esta na imagem acima, recorremos a tabela verdade como esta que está abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Como [nessa explicação](http://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1003217-resolvido-o-que-%C3%A9-e-para-que-serve-a-tabela-da-verdade/) se você precisa concentrar sua aplicação em uma só saida, você pode usar a tabela verdade para saber quais entradas você precisa.

Digamos que você tem um sistema de alarmes com dois sensores e você precisa codificar esse sistema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

^ = AND

V = OR

V_ = XOR

Com essa tabela você consegue saber em quais casos o seu alarme irá soar, precisa que soe quando dois sensores forem ativados? use `sensor1 AND sensor2`, apenas quando um ou mais sensor for ativo? use `sensor1 OR sensor2` ,quando exclusivamente um sensor for ativo? use `sensor1 XOR sensor2`

É um exemplo básico e fácil de entender.