# Simplificação de expressão booleana

Tags: álgebra-booleana

Boa noite, galera!

Estou a realizar um trabalho que tenho que simplificar uma expressão algébrica booleana de um circuito:

[image: circuito]

E a expressão mais simples que achei foi essa:

[image: expressão]

Mas acho que ela pode ser mais simples, alguém teria uma solução melhor que esta?

Comment: A fórmula está correta. Sua intenção é ter menos níveis de porta `and`/porta `or`?

Comment: Essa questão trata de uma das ferramentas usadas para diminuir a profundidade para o mínimo possível de portas n-árias, o mapa de Karnaugh: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228005/64969

Comment: Desculpe ter trocado o NOR com NAND. Já arrumei as duas respostas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta resposta é uma solução por meio de redução de expressões booleanas. Também postei [uma outra resposta baseada na análise da tabela-verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252366/132).

A primeira porta NOR na figura produz isso:

```
(1) j = NOT (a OR b OR c)
```

A porta NOT abaixo dessa NOR:

```
(2) k = NOT b
```

A porta XOR:

```
(3) m = d XOR k
```

A porta NOT acima da XOR:

```
(4) n = NOT d
```

A penúltima porta NAND:

```
(5) p = NOT (j AND n)
```

A porta final:

```
(6) f = NOT (p AND m)
```

Substituindo-se (5) em (6):

```
(7) f = NOT (NOT (j AND n) AND m)
```

Substituindo-se (4) em (7):

```
(8) f = NOT (NOT (j AND NOT d) AND m)
```

Substituindo-se (3) em (8):

```
(9) f = NOT (NOT (j AND NOT d) AND (d XOR k))
```

Substituindo-se (2) em (9):

```
(10) f = NOT (NOT (j AND NOT d) AND (d XOR NOT b))
```

Substituindo-se (1) em (10):

```
(10) f = NOT (NOT (NOT (a OR b OR c) AND NOT d) AND (d XOR NOT b))
```

Essa é a expressão equivalente. Agora, vamos simplificá-la. Aplicando a lei de Morgan nos parênteses mais internos de (10):

```
z = NOT (a OR b OR c)
f = NOT (NOT (z AND NOT d) AND (d XOR NOT b))
z = NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c
(11) f = NOT (NOT ((NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c) AND NOT d) AND (d XOR NOT b))
```

Aplicando a lei de Morgan de novo em (11):

```
z = NOT ((NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c) AND NOT d)
x = (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c)
y = NOT d
z = NOT (x AND y)
z = NOT x OR NOT y
z = NOT (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c) OR d
(12) f = NOT ((NOT (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c) OR d) AND (d XOR NOT b))
```

Mais uma vez:

```
z = NOT (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c)
z = a OR b OR c
(13) f = NOT (((a OR b OR c) OR d) AND (d XOR NOT b))
```

De novo:

```
x = ((a OR b OR c) OR d)
y = (d XOR NOT b)
f = NOT (x AND y)
f = NOT x OR NOT y
(14) f = NOT ((a OR b OR c) OR d) OR NOT (d XOR NOT b)
```

Simplificando os parênteses:

```
(15) f = NOT (a OR b OR c OR d) OR NOT (d XOR NOT b)
```

Aplicando de Morgan de novo:

```
z = NOT (a OR b OR c OR d)
z = NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c AND NOT d
(16) f = (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c AND NOT d) OR NOT (d XOR NOT b)
```

Considerando que `(x XOR NOT y)` é a equivalente a `(x <-> y)`, então:

```
(17) f = (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c AND NOT d) OR NOT (d <-> b)
```

Considerando que `NOT (x <-> y)` é a equivalente a `(x XOR y)`, então:

```
(18) f = (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c AND NOT d) OR (d XOR b)
```

Considerando que `(x XOR y)` é equivalente a `(x AND NOT y) OR (NOT x AND y)`:

```
(19) f = (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c AND NOT d) OR (d AND NOT b) OR (NOT d AND b)
```

Agora, temos duas possibilidades, agrupar o `NOT d AND alguma-coisa`. Ou agrupar o `NOT b AND alguma-coisa`. Vamos começar com o `NOT d`:

```
(20a) f = (NOT d AND ((NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c) OR b)) OR (d AND NOT b)
```

Distribuindo-se o `OR b`:

```
(21a) f = (NOT d AND (NOT a OR b) AND (NOT b OR b) AND (NOT c OR b)) OR (d AND NOT b)
```

Ora, `NOT b OR b` é verdadeiro! Então:

```
(22a) f = (NOT d AND (NOT a OR b) AND TRUE AND (NOT c OR b)) OR (d AND NOT b)
```

E temos que `(x AND TRUE) = x`. Logo:

```
(23a) f = (NOT d AND (NOT a OR b) AND (NOT c OR b)) OR (d AND NOT b)
```

Colocando-se o `b` em evidência de novo:

```
(24a) f = (NOT d AND ((NOT a AND NOT c) OR b)) OR (d AND NOT b)
```

Distribuindo-se o `NOT d AND`:

```
(25a) f = (NOT d AND NOT a AND NOT c) OR (NOT d AND b) OR (d AND NOT b)
```

Considerando que `(NOT d AND b) OR (d AND NOT b)` é o mesmo que `(d XOR b)`:

```
(26a) f = (NOT a AND NOT c AND NOT d) OR (d XOR b)
```

Se tivéssemos agrupado com o `NOT b` ao invés do `NOT d`:

```
(20b) f = (NOT b AND ((NOT a AND NOT c AND NOT d) OR d)) OR (NOT d AND b)
```

Distribuindo-se o `OR d`:

```
(21b) f = (NOT b AND (NOT a OR d) AND (NOT c OR d) AND (NOT d OR d)) OR (NOT d AND b)
```

Ora, `NOT d OR d` é verdadeiro! Então:

```
(22b) f = (NOT b AND (NOT a OR d) AND (NOT c OR d) AND TRUE) OR (NOT d AND b)
```

E temos que `(x AND TRUE) = x`. Logo:

```
(23b) f = (NOT b AND (NOT a OR d) AND (NOT c OR d)) OR (NOT d AND b)
```

Colocando-se o `b` em evidência de novo:

```
(24b) f = (NOT b AND ((NOT a AND NOT c) OR d)) OR (NOT d AND b)
```

Distribuindo-se o `NOT b AND`:

```
(25b) f = (NOT b AND NOT a AND NOT c) OR (NOT b AND d) OR (NOT d AND b)
```

Considerando que `(NOT b AND d) OR (NOT d AND b)` é o mesmo que `(d XOR b)`:

```
(26b) f = (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c) OR (d XOR b)
```

Temos como resultados:

- **`f = (NOT a AND NOT c AND NOT d) OR (d XOR b)`**.
- **`f = (NOT a AND NOT b AND NOT c) OR (d XOR b)`**.

Essas são as possíveis soluções.

Comment: Creio que está seja a solução mais completa que achei, simplesmente sensacional! Muito obrigado pela ajuda e contribuição,amigo!

Comment: em (1) você faz menção a uma porta NAND, quando na verdade é uma porta NOT OR.

Answer (score 3):

Esta resposta é uma solução por meio de análise da tabela-verdade. Também postei [uma outra resposta baseada em redução de expressões booleanas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252367/132).

Vamos ver como fica a tabela-verdade:

```
A B C D F
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

Vamos reorganizar as colunas, colocando na ordem `CABD` e permutando as linhas de acordo para ficar na ordem onde os números das quatro colunas da esquerda crescem em ordem binária do 0000 até o 1111:

```
C A B D F
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

Observe que os valores de `F` da primeira metade da tabela são quase idênticos aos da segunda, com exceção da primeira linha de cada (0000 e 1000). Vamos ver o que há de especial nessas linhas (e para essa parte, o `C` não importa):

```
A B D F
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

Observe que os casos onde a saída é um são os casos `B XOR D`.

Voltando na primeira linha de cada metade da tabela:

```
C A B D F
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0
```

Isso daí equivale a `(NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C AND NOT D)`.

Juntando as duas subexpressões temos:

```
(NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C AND NOT D) OR (B XOR D)
```

No entanto, se voltarmos a olhar na tabela, dá para simplificar `(NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C AND NOT D)` cortando uma (mas não as duas) subexpressões `NOT B` ou `NOT D`. Assim, chega-se em duas possíveis soluções:

- `(NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C) OR (B XOR D)`
- `(NOT A AND NOT C AND NOT D) OR (B XOR D)`

Comment: Na terceira tabela vc diz ter colocado o C na frente, mas apenas trocou a leta, e a coluna permanece a mesma...

Comment: @Dwcleb Não. Observe a coluna do F. Onde era "*B=1, C=0, D=1, F=0*", agora é "*C=0, B=1, D=1, F=0*". Onde era "*B=1, C=1, D=1, F=0*", agora é "*C=1, B=1, D=1, F=0*". Não apenas permutei as colunas, mas também as linhas para ficar na ordem 000 -> 111.

Comment: @Dwcleb Editei a resposta para explicar melhor.