# Simplificação de expressão lógica

Tags: álgebra-booleana

Tenho resolvido algumas questões de simplificação de expressões lógicas, mas tenho sentido certa dificuldade na simplificação delas.

Como essa abaixo:

[image: iResolução]

Foi me dado esse circuito lógico mostrado na figura para que eu descobrisse a saída mais simplificada possível. Eu cheguei até o resultado mostrado, aplicando a lei de Morgan na última liga, primeira expressão.

Mas estou com dúvida se esta realmente simplificada e se está simplificada da forma correta.

Há outro caminho?

A expressão esta correta ou a lei aplicada foi equivocada?

Comment: Conhece o [Mapa de Karnaugh](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228005/5878)?

Comment: SIm, @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Para de adicionar a tag, não é assim que o site funciona. A duvida é sobre algebra booleanaa, nao adianta ficar adicionando tag  desnecessária que nao ajuda em nada a filtrar a pergunta. Sugiro que pare, senao sua pergunta vai ser bloqueada pra edicao ai será pior pra voce.

Comment: A tag [tag:arquitetura-computadores] cita circuitos lógicos, mas no contexto de quando estes são aplicados dentro do funcionamento de um computador, em como ele interage dentro da arquitetura em questão. Sua pergunta é apenas sobre álgebra booleana.

Comment: Tente aplicar o mapa de Karnaugh e compare os resultados. Com o mapa você chegará, por definição, na expressão lógica mais simples possível. Construa a tabela verdade, veja qual dos mapas (1 ou 0) aplicar e faça. Para 3 entradas o mapa fica bastante simples e rápido de fazer;

Comment: A f seria um xnor e não um xor

Comment: Verdade @Ken, obrigado pela observação

Comment: Bom, a princípio não encontrei nenhum erro, e é normal ter dificuldade para achar a menor simplificação booleana dessa forma. Se quiseres chegar a menor simplificação possível, sugiro dar uma olhada sobre mapa de karnaugh. Se pesquisar no google vão ter vários sites e vídeos a respeito. Um deles é o do próprio me salva -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YW-ylq0gE5w