# função que decide se pode subir em um brinquedo JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, funções

obs: estou usando uma plataforma de aprendizado, estou a tempos tentando decifrar o que da errado. vou deixar a questao a abaixo e o meu codigo.
No parque de diversões da cidade, eles instalaram uma nova montanha-russa e nos pediram ajuda para que pudéssemos notificar as pessoas, se poderiam entrar ou não, antes de fazer a fila. Os requisitos para uma pessoa poder entrar no brinquedo são:
edit1: o próprio sistema fornece as variaveis.

Atingir a altura mínima de 1,5 m (ou 1,2 m, se acompanhada por um adulto)
Não ter qualquer problema cardíaco
Defina a função podeSubir, recebendo 3 parâmetros: alturaPessoa (numero), vemComCompania (booleano), temProblemaCardiaco (booleano), retorne true ou false conforme o caso. Levar em conta as condições necessárias mencionadas acima.

linha de codigo:

```js
function podeSubir(alturaPessoa, vemComCompania, temProblemaCardiaco){
  return alturaPessoa >= 1.5 && temProblemaCardiaco == !temProblemaCardiaco || alturaPessoa >= 1.2 && vemComCompania == vemComCompania && temProblemaCardiaco == !temProblemaCardiaco ;
}
```

esse codigo nao supre alguns testes, mas mesmo eu martelando ainda nao vai. se puderem ajudar...

Comment: Consegue nos explicar esse trecho: `temProblemaCardiaco == !temProblemaCardiaco`?

Comment: como o proprio sistema fornece os valores, entao só usei o parametro para comprar a ele mesmo como forma de negação

Comment: E quando uma valor será igual a ele mesmo negado?

Comment: boa pergunta, pensando bem, mas isso foi só uma tentativa perante a varias, usei sem a exclamação mas sainda nao vai

Comment: Ok, então entendo que você está tentando escrever código sem entender o que o código faz, o que é um erro grave, então recomendo que faça o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) da sua solução e ver exatamente o que ela faz.

Comment: Vale lembrar que você pode utilizar o [mapa de karnaugh](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228005/5878) para construir sua expressão lógica.

Comment: obrigado pela orientação!!!

Answer (score 3):

Condições para ser `true`: `NÃO temProblemaCardiaco E (altura >= 1,5) OU (altura >= 1,2 E vemComCompanhia)`, agora basta traduzir isso para o javascript:

```js
function podeSubir(alturaPessoa, vemComCompania, temProblemaCardiaco){
  return !temProblemaCardiaco && (alturaPessoa >= 1.5) || (alturaPessoa >= 1.2 && vemComCompania);
}
```

Lembre-se sempre de usar `()` para definir a prioridade de execução. E no começo, leia o problema, escreva ou desenha o que tem que ser feito e depois implemente na linguagem.

E outra coisa você comparar uma variável com sua negação, exemplo `temProblemaCardiaco === !temProblemaCardiaco`, sempre será **false**, porque sempre for `true` você compara com `false`, o que gera `false`, e quando for `false`, você compara com `true`, o que de novo gera `false`. Nesse caso, basta saber se a variável é ou não true.

Comment: Há um problema de curto circuito na sua expressão lógica retornando `true` quando `alturaPessoa` é maior que 1.5 sem avaliar se possui problema cardíaco.

Comment: Tem razão, vou consertar, valeu!

Comment: Perfeito. Até é legal trazer a condição de problema cardíaco para o início, por ser mandatória e não exigir avaliar a idade da pessoa se a mesma possuir problema cardíaco.

Comment: Sim, sempre tento lembar do `curto-circuito`, mas algumas vezes escapa haha. Valeu!

Comment: me sinto um pouco frustrado ao ver que a resposta parecia bem simples, mas imagino como qualquer coisa, é necessário pratica. mas obg pela ajuda rapazes, se puderem deixar uma sugestão como estudar melhor, ficarei grato!

Comment: Acontece no começo, depois vai pegando com a prática. E como o @Woss citou, depois da uma pesquisada em `avaliações de curto-circuito`, é uma boa prática e deixa o código mais otimizado.