# Como simplificar a expressão lógica (~x Ʌ ~y Ʌ ~z) V (x Ʌ ~y) V (z Ʌ ~y)?

Tags: lógica, álgebra-booleana

Me deparei com a seguinte questão de lógica em um teste de nivelamento que fiz que não soube resolver... alguém poderia me explicar o raciocínio da questão?

Considerando que x, y e z sejam proposições simples e ~x, ~y e ~z, respectivamente, as suas negações, a proposição composta de (~x Ʌ ~y Ʌ ~z) V (x Ʌ ~y) V (z Ʌ ~y) é equivalente à:

a) x V z.

b) ~x.

c) ~y.

d) y Ʌ ~z.

Legenda:

- Ʌ: símbolo de Conjunção ("and"/ "e")
- V: símbolo de Disjunção ("or" / "ou")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dada a expressão e considerando as propriedades da álgebra booleana:

```
= (~x * ~y * ~z) + (x * ~y) + (z * ~y)
```

> Simplificando a notação com o operador `and` como sendo `*` e `or` como sendo `+`

Pela propriedade distributiva da multiplicação, podemos *colocar o termo comum em evidência*:

```
= ~y * ((~x * ~z) + x + z)
```

Dada a equivalência de Morgan, em que `~a * ~b = ~(a + b)`, tem-se:

```
= ~y * (~(x + z) + (x + z))
```

Sabe-se que `a + ~a = 1`, para qualquer `a`, então:

```
= ~y * 1
```

Sabe-se que `a * 1 = a`, para qualquer `a`, então:

```
= ~y
```

Portanto, `(~x Ʌ ~y Ʌ ~z) V (x Ʌ ~y) V (z Ʌ ~y)` é equivalente a `~y`.

Se não for muito fã da álgebra, você pode analisar as 8 possibilidades distintas de entrada calculando a saída para construir um [Mapa de Karnaugh](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228005/5878) e, a partir do mapa, simplificar a sua expressão.

Comment: E no fim, o y não serviu pra nada.. hehe

Comment: @RogerioSantos ou melhor, só ele serve xD

Answer (score 1):

Responderia c) ~y.

Vamos chamar com o 'til' de negativo e sem positivo, pra facilitar o entendimento.

Se observar, se o y for negativo (~y) vai satisfazer em pelo menos uma das outras proposições, independente da 'polaridade' do 'x' e 'z'.

Ou seja, se ~y, não importa o restante pois atenderá uma das 3, logo é equivalente.

**EDIT**

Explicando melhor. a pergunta se refere a equivalencia, ou seja, qual condição faz exatamente a mesma coisa que a outra.

Na questão  `(~x Ʌ ~y Ʌ ~z) V (x Ʌ ~y) V (z Ʌ ~y`), trazendo para a programação seria :

```
var x, y, z :bool; //vamos pensar em true como natural e false como ~(inevrsão)
```

Se assumirmos !y (~y) a expressão abaixo será exatamente a mesma coisa, melhor falando, ela só vai entrar no if exatamente na mesma condição (se y for verdadeiro, não entra, pois na função abaixo tbm não vai entrar)

```
//       c1                c2           c3
if((!x && !y && !z) || (x && !y) || (z && !y)) {
     //faça alguma coisa
}
```

Logo:

1. se `!y e z` -> entra na c3, não importa o valor  de x, pois a condição não pede isso
2. Se `!y e x` -> entra na c2, não importa o valor  de x, pois a condição não pede isso
3. Se `!y e !x e !y` -> entra na c1 se `y` ou `x = true`, entra numa das opções anteriores.
4. se `y` -> independe do `x ou z`, pois nenhuma condição atende este valor cairia no `else`.

Portanto, se olharmos acima, se !y não importa o valor dos outros 2, a expressão, será verdadeira, assim como, se y, a expressão será falsa, independe do x ou y.

**Conclusão:**

`if(!y)` tem o mesmo resultado que `if((!x && !y && !z) || (x && !y) || (z && !y))`, logo `c) ~y`, pois  `(~y)` terá o mesmo resultado que `( (~x Ʌ ~y Ʌ ~z) V (x Ʌ ~y) V (z Ʌ ~y))` equivale.

> `Y` positivo, altera se atende ou não a condição, mas a pergunta é uma condição que equivalha a outra, e o `y` não existe neste contexto.

Comment: E se y for positivo? Há garantia que o retorno da expressão será falso?

Comment: Não há garantia, mas a questão é o que é equivalente àquela condição, ou seja, se você escrever aquilo tudo ou apenas ~y, será a mesma coisa, y positivo é outra história.. hehe

Comment: Se é "outra história", então pode não ser equivalente. Para ser equivalente o retorno deve ser o mesmo para uma mesma entrada. Basta aplicar as regras da álgebra de Boole e simplificar a expressão.

Comment: Não, olha na expressão:  (~x Ʌ ~y Ʌ ~z) V (x Ʌ ~y) V (z Ʌ ~y)  não existe y positivo, o y positivo é indiferente para ela. se o y for positivo não atenderá a expressão em nenhum dos casos, logo retorna falso, então, está errado.

Comment: Poderia esclarecer melhor o que quis dizer com "não existe y positivo"? O termo `~y` significa valor invertido de `y`; se a entrada `y` é 1, `~y` será 0; se `y` for 0, `~y` será 1.

Comment: Para constar, eu negativei a resposta porque, embora a resposta é a correta, não demonstra a análise que prova a equivalência entre as expressões. Como muito utilizado no processo de demonstração por negação, centenas de casos de sucesso não provam a veracidade de uma afirmação, mas basta apenas um caso de negação para provar o contrário. Ou seja, mostra que a expressão é equivalente em um caso não demonstra a equivalência em todos os casos.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu a pergunta.

Comment: Por que acha isso? Poderia esclarecer?

Comment: Editei a resposta