# Por que meu while não funciona?

Tags: python, while, operador-lógico

Estou estudando estrutura de repetições e em um dos exercícios eu tinha que verificar o sexo digitado, então fiz o seguinte código:

```
sexo = input("digite m ou f: ")
while sexo != 'f' or sexo != 'm':
   sexo = input("digite m ou f: ")
```

No entanto, não funciona.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 11):

Neste caso deve usar um `and` e não um `or`. Na forma atual a condição sempre será verdadeira porque pelo menos uma das duas sub-expressões será verdadeira, é impossível algo ser igual a duas coisas diferentes, sempre uma será diferente. Se a letra for `f` ela será diferente de `m` e se for `m`, será diferente de `f` se for outra coisa, ambas serão verdadeiras, mas nem importa, basta uma ser que tudo fica verdadeiro.

O desejado é ser diferente das duas ao mesmo tempo, isto se dá com o `and`, assim ambas precisam ser verdadeiras para continuar no laço e é impossível ambas serem verdadeiras se digitar ou `f` ou `m`.

```
sexo = input("digite m ou f: ")
while sexo != 'f' and sexo != 'm':
     sexo = input("digite m ou f: ")
print(sexo)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1ceRCY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uruqdocq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para futura referência](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/LogicOperators.py).

Veja a [tabela verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227811/101) para entender a diferença entre os operadores. E os [operadores lógicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101) em ação.

Eu entendo a confusão porque você quer aceitar que uma **ou** outra letra sejam aceitáveis. O que confunde é que o laço está pedindo o inverso, ele não está testando se aceita uma ou outra, ele está testando se **não** é uma ou outra, aí tem que inverter o operador. Se sentir mais confortável pode escrever de outra forma que usa o `or`, muitos vão considerar que exprime melhor a intenção:

```
sexo = ''
while not (sexo == 'f' or sexo == 'm'):
    sexo = input("digite m ou f: ")
print(sexo)
```

Note que eu fiz outra melhoria. O `input` estava repetido, assim não fica mais e o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: kkkkkk é verdade. Mds como eu sou burro!!!

Comment: Não é essa a questão, é só entender o funcionamento dos operadores, como eles costumam ser novos para a maioria das pessoas, não se ensina na matemática, apesar de ser totalmente matemático as pessoas confundem. O `or` é como se fosse uma soma, o `and` é como se fosse uma multiplicação, sempre fazendo com 0 e 1.

Answer (score 1):

Sua condição de parada é a seguinte: `while sexo != 'f' or sexo != 'm':`, ou seja, quando o usuário digitar algo diferente de 'f' ou de 'm', continua no laço, e ele nunca digitará uma letra igual as duas.

Para que ele saia com uma das opções aceitas, sua condição deve ser para continuar enquanto ele não digitar uma ou outra:

```
sexo = input("digite m ou f: ")
while sexo != 'f' and sexo != 'm':
     sexo = input("digite m ou f: ")
print(sexo)
```

Answer (score -3):

Não funciona por causa da condicional do while que você colocou.
Não tem como sua string "sexo" ser igual a "f" e igual a "m" ao mesmo tempo, ou seja, ou é igual a um ou é igual ao outro; sendo assim, ela sempre será diferente de  pelo menos um dos dois, fazendo com que a condicional do while seja sempre verdadeira. A substituição do "or" por "and" resolve o problema.