# Diferença entre operadores && e ||

Tags: javascript, operadores

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre:

```
window.RM = window.RM || {};
```

E:

```
window.RM = window.RM && {};
```

Talvez os exemplos não estejam corretos, mas gostaria de saber a diferença entre os operadores `&&` e `||` em exemplos semelhantes aos citados acima.

Nota: Eu já sei usá-los em condicionais, no contexto de operadores lógicos, mas não sei diferenciá-los em casos como os demonstrados acima.

Comment: Conhece o termo _falsy_? Ajuda no entendimento desses operadores

Comment: Não conheço....

Comment: Tenho certeza que isto já foi respondido, mas não posso pesquisar agora.

Comment: Sobre _falsy_ e _truthy_: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/64969

Comment: Entendi. Mas qual a relação disso com a minha questão?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Minhas buscas procurando uma resposta para essa questão foram infrutíferas, deveria estar usando as palavras erradas. Então, lá vai uma resposta

Esses operadores que você se refere são operadores booleanos. Isso significa que eles operam dentro do universo matemático chamado "álgebra de Boole". Essa álgebra difere da nossa álgebra tradicional pois ela não trabalha com números, mas apenas com dois valores.

Essa álgebra funciona sobre 3 axiomas:

- lei da identidade (`a == a` sempre)
- lei da não contradição (nada pode ser e não ser ao mesmo tempo)
- lei do terceiro excluído (ou você é verdade ou é falso, não pode ser algo no meio, um terceiro valor)

[Leia mais aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought?wprov=sfti1).

Os operadores usados são o `&&` "E" (*and* em inglês fica menos ambíguo) e o `||` "OU" (em inglês *or*).

Eles funcionam de determinado jeito, que pode ser visto em [tabelas verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227811/64969). Note como o resultado depende da primeira variável.

- Caso a primeira variável seja falsa, o "E" será falso como um todo; caso contrário será  o valor da segunda variável
- Caso a primeira variável seja falsa, o "OU" terá o valor da segunda variável; caso contrário, basta saber que a primeira variável é verdadeira

Então o JavaScript funciona assim para os seus operadores booleanos. Inclusive, se ele já puder determinar o valor da expressão booleana olhando só para o primeiro operando, ele nem vai atrás de calcular o valor do segundo operando. O nome dessa estratégia de não computar coisas desnecessárias é "curto circuito".

Mas no caso você não está trabalhando com valores verdade. Ou está? Veja, no JavaScript, eles pegam de modo mais leve sobre o tipo do objeto. Você pode não estar lidando com booleanos, mas seus valores podem ser "verdadeiriformes" ou "falsiformes" (não confundir com "falciforme").

Uma coisa com "forma verdadeira" ou "verdadeiriforme" é chamado de *truthy* em JavaScript e, para tudo que envolve expressões booleanas, são considerados verdadeiros. Já os com "forma falsa" ou "falsiforme" são os *falsy* e são para todos os efeitos equivalentes ao falso booleano.

Você pode encontrar mais sobre esses termos nas respostas [desta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/64969).

Então, o que está acontecendo?

No caso do "E", caso `window.RM` seja *truthy*, a expressão vai retornar `{}`, caso contrário vai retornar `window.RM` mesmo. Como isso está sendo atribuído na variável `window.RM`, isso parece ser um jeito de "zerar" o objeto caso ele tenha algum valor.

Já no caso do "OU", parece mais uma espécie de inicialização do objeto `window.RM`, pois seu valor só é sobrescrito com `{}` caso ele já esteja *falsy*, caso contrário (caso seja *truthy*) ele não tem seu valor alterado.

Answer (score 11):

Isso se chama [Avaliação de curto-circuito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito).

Quando você usa o operador `&&` (AND), só será assumido o valor do segundo argumento se o primeiro for *verdadeiro*:

```
window.RM = window.RM && {};
// resultado: "undefined", porque window.RM não tem valor.
```

**O que é ser verdadeiro?**

Diferente de vazio, *null*, 0 e `false`.

```
window.RM = 0;
window.RM = window.RM && {};
// resultado: "0", porque window.RM é igual a zero.
```

Outro exemplo:

```
window.RM = '0';
window.RM = window.RM && {};
// resultado: "{}", porque window.RM é igual a zero, mas zero é uma string e não um número.
```

No operador `||` (OR), é o contrário, onde o primeiro argumento deve ser *falso* para assumir o valor do segundo:

```
window.RM = 0;
window.RM = window.RM || {};
// resultado: "{}", porque window.RM é igual a zero.
```

Outro exemplo:

```
window.RM = window.RM || {};
// resultado: "{}", porque window.RM não possui valor, é "undefined".
```

E mais um:

```
window.RM = true;
window.RM = window.RM || {};
// resultado: "true", porque window.RM é true, contrário de false.
```

Resumindo, o `&&` *pergunta* para o argumento à esquerda se ele é verdadeiro, se ele responder que sim, ele pega o da direita. Já o `||` pergunta à esquerda se ele é falso, se responder que sim, pega o da direita.

Comment: Já vejo o bate-papo dos operadores e dos operandos =]

Comment: Complementando a ótima explicação, [no site do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos) tem mais exemplos.

Answer (score 4):

Estes operadores são usados em comparações, o valor à direita será usado:

- (caso `||`) quando o valor booleano do comparador à esquerda der `false`
- (caso `&&`) quando o valor booleano do comparador à esquerda der `true`

Pode também dizer-se:

- (caso `||`) o primeiro valor que validar como `true` o seu valor Booleano será retornado (avaliando da esquerda para a direita), ou `false` caso ambos falhem
- (caso `&&`) o valor do segundo operando (à direita) será retornado caso o valor Booleano do primeiro operando seja `true`, mesmo que o valor booleano do operando à direita for `false`, ele será retornado. (Ou seja: `true && ''` retorna `''` e não `false`)

No caso específico dos exemplos que mostras:

- o `||` funciona como `fallback`, ou seja caso o valor à esquerda não exista (valide como `false`) o resultado dessa atribuição será um objeto vazio.
- o `&&` será usado e atribuído a `window.RM` caso o valor à esquerda do `&&` resolver como `true`. Caso o valor à esquerda não valide a atribuição será com o valor do primeiro operando (que tem o valor Booleano `false`).

Exemplos:

```
false || 25 // 25 (o primeiro falha, o segundo é usado pois valida como `true`, o valor final é 25)
true  || false // true (o primeiro é usado, o segundo é ignorado, o valor final é 25)
false || false // false (o primeiro falha, o segundo falha)

false && true // true (o primeiro falha, o segundo é ignorado pois o primeiro já falhou)
true  && 25 // 25 (o primeiro valida, o segundo é retornado, o valor final é 25)
true  && false // false (o primeiro passa, o segundo falha, o resultado é `false`)
null  && true // null (note-se que retorna `null` e não `false`)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Operadores lógicos

Os operadores lógicos retornam **verdadeiro (V)** ou **falso (F)** de acordo com seus
operandos. 
[image: ex1]

Os operadores lógicos também são conhecidos como **conectivos**, pois são
utilizados para formar novas proposições a partir da junção de duas outras.
Para entender o funcionamento de operadores lógicos, vamos recorrer ao
nosso exemplo das variáveis inteiras, **A** e **B** onde A = 5 e B = 8. O Quadro abaixo
exibe exemplos de expressões que usam operadores lógicos.
[image: ex2]

Você deve ter notado, pelos exemplos anteriores:

- quando utilizamos o operador lógico E(**&&**), o resultado só será verdadeiro se
  as duas condições relacionadas forem verdadeiras;
- para o operador OU(**||**), basta que uma das condições seja verdadeira para
  que o resultado seja verdadeiro;
- em consequência: com o operador OU(**||**), para que o resultado seja falso as
  duas condições devem ser falsas.