# Como passar como dois array como argumento dentro uma função?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [4, 5];
function mover (arg1,arg2){
  return arg1 && arg2;
}
```

Minha dúvida: Eu estou fazendo certo? Porque eu esperava na resposta `[1, 2, 3] , [4, 5]`, e como pode ver abaixo, ele só traz uma resposta. E por que o console traz a resposta duas vezes? Outra dúvida, o array só pode ser inserido na função uma única vez?

Resposta do console:

```
console.log(mover(arr1,arr2));

[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
=> undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

Não é possível retornar dois valores em uma função. Cada `return` que você dá só retorna um valor. Desse modo, se você quiser retornar mais de um valor por uma função, deverá utilizar um array de tamanho fixo. Além disso, conforme sugerido nos comentários pelo [@leofalmeida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/167927/leofalmeida), também é possível utilizar objetos.

### Retornando dois valores utilizando array:

Por exemplo, considere a função abaixo. Quero que ela retorne o primeiro parâmetro **e** o segundo parâmetro:

```js
function twoValues(a, b) {
  // Note que estou retornando um array com os dois
  // valores que quero retornar.
  return [a, b];
}

console.log(twoValues('Luiz', 'Felipe'));
```

No seu caso, se você quiser retornar dois arrays:

```js
function twoValues(a, b) {
  return [a, b];
}

console.log(twoValues([1, 2], [3, 4]));
```

### Retornando valores utilizando objetos:

Também é possível retornar um objeto. Essa abordagem é ideal se você desejar retornar múltiplos valores ao mesmo tempo. Um exemplo seria:

```js
function twoValuesViaObject(a, b) {
  return {
    first: a,
    second: b
    // ...
  }
}

console.log(twoValuesViaObject([1, 2], [3, 4]));
```

Para saber mais sobre os objetos, leia [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos).

---

## Operador `&&`

E no seu caso, o operador `&&` não funciona para retornar dois valores, já que essa nem é a função dele. Naquele caso, ele está fazendo uma [avaliação de curto-circuito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito). Para saber mais sobre elas, veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274110/69296).

Como você pode ver, no seu exemplo:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [4, 5];

function mover(arg1,arg2) {
  return arg1 && arg2;
}

console.log(mover(arr1, arr2)); // [4, 5]
```

Somente o `arr2` está sendo retornado, detrimento da avaliação de curto-circuito. Basicamente, como o `arr1` é um valor *truthy*, o segundo operando será retornado. *Para saber mais, leia a pergunta linkada acima.*

---

## Saiba mais...

Para aprofundamento, recomendo ler sobre a [atribuição via desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao), que pode ajudar o trabalho com objetos e arrays. ;)

Comment: Luiz  vendo o seu exemplo acima, se a fosse um array e b fosse outro array como ficaria?

Comment: Não tem diferença. É a mesma coisa, já que você pode ter _arrays_ dentro de _arrays_ (não há limite para isso – pelo menos não conheço). Editei a pergunta adicionando mais um exemplo...

Comment: Só complementando a resposta: pode se retornar um objeto também, aí segue a mesma regra do array: `return { primeiro: a, segundo: b }`. A vantagem é poder nomear os retornos.

Comment: @leofalmeida, de fato! Objetos podem ser bem úteis nesse caso se for necessário retornar muitos valores. Posso editar a resposta acrescentando esse detalhe? :)

Comment: À vontade haha! :)

Comment: Uma ultima pergunta onde diabos vc usa push e pop? não vejo aplicação isso no mercado!

Comment: Crie uma outra pergunta para isso, assim não fugimos do escopo dessa... :) Se essa resposta te ajudou, não esqueça de aceitá-la, clicando no ícone de check (✅) no canto superior esquerdo da resposta.