# Separar parte inteira e decimal em um número usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo que consiste em:

Pegar um número, como por exemplo `46.5`.

Percorrer esse valor e dividir a parte inteira da flutuante, ou seja, a parte inteira vai ficar em uma variável, e a flutuante em outra.

Utilizando o exemplo acima ficaria:

```
partInteira = 46
partFluante = 5
```

> Quero utilizar esse algoritmo para uma função de arredondamento no Google Sheets.
>
> **Segue abaixo um algoritmo feito em Python, para facilitar o entendimento da ideia:**

```
def arredondar(numero):
    digitos = str(numero)

    partInteira = ""
    partFlutuante = 0
    tamanho = len(digitos)

    for i in range(tamanho):
        if digitos[i] == ".":
           partInteira = int(partInteira)
           partFlutuante = int(digitos[i+1])

           if partFlutuante > 5:
              return partInteira + 1
           elif partFlutuante < 5:
              return partInteira - 1
           else:
              return numero

        else:
           if i == (tamanho-1):
              return numero
           partInteira += digitos[i]
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode transformar o número em uma string e separar a parte inteira da parte decimal utilizando o [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), um método das strings no JavaScript.

Algo assim:

```js
const num = 46.5;

// Convertemos o número para string:
const str = num.toString();

// Separamos nas duas partes.
const splitted = str.split('.');

// Parte inteira:
const int = parseInt(splitted[0]);

// Parte decimal ('0' por padrão).
const decimal = parseInt(splitted[1] || 0);

console.log(int, decimal);
```

Você pode inclusive reduzir bastante o código com [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [atribuição por desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao):

```js
const num = 46.5;

const [int = 0, decimal = 0] = num.toString()
  .split('.')
  .map((num) => parseInt(num));
  
console.log(int, decimal);
```

Você pode inclusive extrair esse comportamento para uma função, retornando um `array` de dois elementos ou um objeto. [Para saber mais, veja esta outra resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/426047/69296)

Algo assim:

```js
function splitNumber(num) {
  const [int = 0, decimal = 0] = num.toString()
    .split('.')
    .map((num) => parseInt(num));
    
  return [int, decimal];
}

// Imagine que esse `arg` vem como parâmetro:
const arg = 46.5;

const [int, decimal] = splitNumber(arg);
console.log(int, decimal);
```

---

Vale lembrar que, embora a pergunta, através de seu exemplo, dê a entender que a intenção é separar os dígitos a partir do separador decimal do número `.`, se a intenção for, de fato, separar a parte inteira da parte fracionária do número, a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/511319/69296) é matematicamente mais adequada.

Desse modo, para o exemplo da pergunta, `46.5`, podem ocorrer haver dois comportamentos:

- Dividir em `46` e `5`, dois números inteiros (adequado conforme o exemplo da pergunta).
- Dividir em `46` e `0.5`, a parte inteira e a parte fracionária (adequado conforme a semântica matemática).

E é importante, ainda, estar ciente dos problemas ligados à notação científica que pode ser retornada por `Number.prototype.toString`, o que pode prejudicar a abordagem das respostas sem uma tratativa mais adequada (a qual provavelmente não entra no escopo da pergunta). Essa problemática é, contudo, perceptível apenas em números muito grandes ou muito pequenos.

Comment: Muito Obrigada pela resposta, só tem um pequeno problema rs, como quero usar esse algoritmo dentro de uma função para arredondamento, o numero utilizado no exemplo, seria pego como paramentro da função: exemplo ** arrendondar(45.6)**

Comment: Então, como mencionei no final da resposta, você pode extrair o comportamento para uma outra função e passar o número que você tem (obtido seja onde for) como argumento. Veja o último exemplo que acabei de adicionar. :-)

Comment: Aaaa, certo. Vc poderia me mostrar um exemplo de como fazer isso?rs não consegui entender muito bem o outro link que você destacou

Comment: Eu acabei de editar a resposta, veja o último exemplo adicionado.

Comment: Entendi =D, grata!!

Comment: Tentei extrair o comportamento, porém está aparecendo o seguite erro: |TypeError: Não é possível chamar o método "toString" de undefined.| Isso acontece quando tento pegar o valor que está vindo como parâmetro

Comment: Tente dar um `console.log` para ver o que esse valor é. Pela mensagem do erro, provavelmente é `undefined` ou `null`, então o problema está com a origem do valor...

Answer (score 3):

Para resolver este problema basta você converter seu número para `string` utilizando o método [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ToString):

```
var numero = 45.5;
var numero_str = numero.toString();
```

Feito isso, utilize a função [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), que vai retornar um array:

```
var numero_split = numero_str.split(".");

// Apenas rodando para verificar no console
console.log(numero_split[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Só queria complementar para indicar alguns detalhes sobre a definição do problema e as soluções das outras respostas. Não é que estejam erradas, mas há alguns poréns a se atentar.

Primeiro, se os números forem, por exemplo, `1.5`, `1.05` e `1.00005`: para estes três casos, é dito que a parte decimal é `5`. Veja:

```js
function splitNumber(num) {
  const [int = 0, decimal = 0] = num.toString()
    .split('.')
    .map((num) => parseInt(num));
    
  return [int, decimal];
}

console.log(splitNumber(1.5)); // [1, 5]
console.log(splitNumber(1.05)); // [1, 5]
console.log(splitNumber(1.00005)); // [1, 5]
```

Mas na verdade a parte decimal do segundo e terceiro números não é exatamente `5`. Em um é `0.05` e no outro é `0.00005` - **esses zeros fazem toda a diferença, pois não é o mesmo valor**.

Então aí vem o outro porém que mencionei, que é a definição do problema: não faz sentido transformar a parte decimal em um inteiro, porque para inteiros o zero à esquerda não faz diferença, mas para casas decimais faz. Portanto, eu sugiro que não faça esta transformação, e mantenha a parte decimal como está, sem converter para inteiro. Assim você não perde as casas decimais.

---

Outro problema é que transformar o número em string nem sempre vai funcionar da forma esperada:

```js
function splitNumber(num) {
  const [int = 0, decimal = 0] = num.toString()
    .split('.')
    .map((num) => parseInt(num));
    
  return [int, decimal];
}

console.log(splitNumber(0.0000005)); // [5, 0]
console.log(splitNumber(10000000000000000000000)); // [1, 0]
console.log(splitNumber(10000000000000000000000.99299284982)); // [1, 0]
```

Isso acontece porque a partir de determinado valor "muito grande" (ou "muito pequeno"), o método `toString` retorna o número representado em notação científica. No caso do `0.0000005`, por exemplo, o resultado de `toString` é `5e-7`. E como a função faz o `split` desta string usando o ponto como separador, o resultado acaba não sendo o esperado ([pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/506307/112052)).

Uma forma de evitar este problema (e também o primeiro, de não preservar todos os zeros das casas decimais) é simplesmente truncar o número para obter a parte inteira, e em seguida subtrair esta parte inteira do número original (assim, o que sobrar é a parte decimal):

```js
function splitNumber(num) {
  const int = Math.trunc(num);
  return [int, num - int];
}

console.log(splitNumber(1.5));
console.log(splitNumber(1.05));
console.log(splitNumber(1.00005));
console.log(splitNumber(0.0000005));
console.log(splitNumber(10000000000000000000000));
console.log(splitNumber(10000000000000000000000.99299284982));
```

Mas claro que agora geramos outros "problemas". No segundo número acima, a parte decimal é `0.05`, mas o resultado acabou sendo `0.050000000000000044`. Isso acontece por causa da [forma como os números de ponto flutuante funcionam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260701/112052). Existe uma explicação mais detalhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/112052), e [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/112052) tem vários outros links que você pode seguir para se aprofundar no assunto. Mas pelo menos não removemos os zeros das casas decimais, o que na minha opinião é uma melhoria.

E no último número, a parte decimal resultante foi zero, já que as casas decimais foram ignoradas por causa [disso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225494). Ou seja, mesmo usando matemática em vez de conversão para strings, ainda estaremos limitados às características de implementação da linguagem (e não tem como fugir muito disso - a menos que você use bibliotecas dedicadas para lidar com valores tão grandes, como [essa](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/)).

Vale lembrar que a solução com `toString` também está sujeita a esse comportamento, já que é algo intrínseco à forma como os números de ponto flutuante funcionam:

```js
function splitNumber(num) {
  const [int = 0, decimal = 0] = num.toString()
    .split('.')
    .map((num) => parseInt(num));
    
  return [int, decimal];
}

var x = 1.05 - 1; // supondo que o número é resultado de algum cálculo
console.log(splitNumber(x)); // [0, 50000000000000050]
```

Se quer evitar isso, aí teria que tratar os números antes (ou depois), seja arredondando, eliminando casas decimais, etc (mas aí acredito que já fuja do escopo da pergunta).