# Como posso trocar elementos de uma string usando os valores de um objeto como argumento?

Tags: javascript, array, string, regex, objetos

Eu tenho este código:

```js
const operators = {
    plus : '+',
    minus : '-',
    multiplied : '*',
    divided : '/'
}

let question = 'What is 4 plus 6?';

let matchs = question.match(/\d|plus|minus|multiplied|divided/g);

matchs = matchs.join(''); 

console.log(matchs) // '4plus6'
```

E gostaria que ele retornasse algo como `'4+6'`.

Minha ideia foi usar o `replace`, porém não sei como poderia passar o `+` como argumento usando objetos.

Meu conhecimento em objetos é muito pouco, então gostaria de conseguir entender um pouco mais sobre, pois vejo resoluções onde um grande número de `if else` pode ser substituido usando objetos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é usar [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), passando como segundo parâmetro uma [função de *callback*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```js
const operators = {
    plus: '+',
    minus: '-',
    multiplied: '*',
    divided: '/'
};

let question = 'What is 4 plus 6? And 4 minus 6, 4 multiplied 6, 4 divided 6';

let s = question.replace(/\b(plus|minus|multiplied|divided)\b/g, function(match, op) {
    return operators[op];
});

console.log(s) // What is 4 + 6? And 4 - 6, 4 * 6, 4 / 6
```

Eu uso o atalho `\b` ([*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), se quiser uma explicação mais detalhada sobre ele, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052)) para especificar que antes e depois do texto não há nenhum caractere alfanumérico (assim eu só pego as palavras "plus", "minus", etc, quando elas estiverem "isoladas" do texto - se tiver algo como "multiplus", a regex ignora).

As palavras ficam entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (e também por causa da ordem de precedência, veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/1mJ8KP/1/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/1mJ8KP/2/) como faz diferença).

Em seguida, eu passo uma função de *callback* que recebe como parâmetros o `match` e o primeiro grupo de captura (que chamei de `op`). Aí, basta retornar o símbolo correspondente ao texto que foi capturado, que está no primeiro grupo (na variável `op`). O resultado da função é o que será usado na substituição, ou seja, ele troca "plus" por "+", "minus" por "-" e assim por diante.

Vale lembrar que o restante do texto (o "What is" e as vírgulas que coloquei no exemplo) não é removido.

---

Se quiser que as palavras sejam substituídas somente se tiver números antes e depois, pode trocar para:

```js
const operators = {
    plus: '+',
    minus: '-',
    multiplied: '*',
    divided: '/'
};

let question = 'What is 4 plus 6? And 4 minus 6, 4 multiplied 6, 4 divided 6, plus without numbers.';

let s = question.replace(/(\d+)\s*\b(plus|minus|multiplied|divided)\b\s*(\d+)/g, function(match, n1, op, n2) {
    return `${n1}${operators[op]}${n2}`;
});

console.log(s) // What is 4+6? And 4-6, 4*6, 4/6, plus without numbers.
```

Agora eu incluí mais 2 grupos de captura com `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos) e com espaços opcionais (`\s*` - zero ou mais espaços), então a função de *callback* deve receber mais argumentos para corresponder a estes grupos adicionais (`n1` é o número antes da operação, `op` é o texto e `n2` é o número depois da operação).

No retorno da função eu troco o texto pelo símbolo da operação e mantenho os números. Eu não coloquei espaço entre eles, mas se quiser por um espaço, bastaria fazer `` return `${n1} ${operators[op]} ${n2}`; ``.

Answer (score 2):

Claro, dá para usar expressão regular, conforme sugere a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482713/69296), mas você também pode dividir a frase por espaços e trocar as "palavras-operadores" pelos respectivos símbolos.

Veja:

```js
const operators = {
  plus: '+',
  minus: '-',
  multiplied: '*',
  divided: '/'
};

const question = 'What is 4 plus 6? And 4 minus 6, 4 multiplied 6, 4 divided 6';

const symbolified = question
  .split(' ')
  .map((word) => operators[word] || word)
  .join(' ');

console.log(symbolified); // What is 4 + 6? And 4 - 6, 4 * 6, 4 / 6
```

Basicamente, divide-se a string original em um *array* de palavras. Para cada uma dessas palavras, verificamos se há correspondência no objeto `operators`. No caso de não existir, a expressão `operators[word]` retorna `undefined`, de modo que a palavra `word` é usada como *fallback* pelo operador `||`, que ali faz [avaliação de curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274110/69296).

Não sei dizer se isso é mais ou menos performático, mas se for algo importante, vale a pena rever depois. :)