# Como formatar um array para saída JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```js
const products = ["camisa-PP", "camisa-M", "camisa-G", "camisa-GG", "camisa-GG", "camiseta-PP", "camiseta-G", "cueca-M", "blusa-XG", "blusa-XG", "blusa-XG", "blusa-P"];

console.log(products)
```

E preciso convertê-lo para que a saída em JSON ocorra assim:

```
{ 
  "camisa": { 
    "PP": 1, 
    "M": 1, 
    "G": 1, 
    "GG": 2 
  }, 
  "camiseta": { 
    "PP": 1, 
    "G": 1 
  }, 
  "cueca": { 
    "M": 1 
  }, 
  "blusa": { 
    "XG": 3, 
    "P": 1 
  }
}
```

Preciso que cada elemento agrupe os tamanhos de cada produto e a quantidade. Como fazer isso?

Até agora consegui apenas separar os valores do array que continha `-` e o transformei em um objeto, mas não tenho ideia de como prosseguir, segue o código abaixo:

```js
const products = ["camisa-PP", "camisa-M", "camisa-G", "camisa-GG", "camisa-GG", "camiseta-PP", "camiseta-G", "cueca-M", "blusa-XG", "blusa-XG", "blusa-XG", "blusa-P"];

let json = products.map(elements => JSON.parse(`{"${elements.split('-').join('":"')}"}`));

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há de se mencionar, antes de tudo, que não há necessidade de utilizar `JSON.parse` aí (montando a string do JSON de forma literal), já que esse é um meio menos performático e mais suscetível a eventuais erros. Ao invés disso, você pode utilizar a própria linguagem para manipular as estruturas de dados diretamente, sem a necessidade de criar strings em JSON.

Tendo isso em vista, há de se entender que o resultado esperado é um objeto e a entrada, um array. Desse modo, você precisa pensar em um jeito de, a partir de um objeto vazio inicial, incrementar os valores conforme se percorre o array. Um exemplo de implementação seria esta:

```js
function groupProducts(arr) {
  // Nosso objeto (vazio) inicial:
  const result = {};
  
  for (const item of arr) {
    // Cada `item` é algo como "camisa-PP".
    // Portanto, podemos utilizar o método `split` para separá-lo em nome e tamanho:
    const [name, size] = item.split('-');
    
    // No caso do `name` da iteração atual ainda não ter sido criado:
    if (!result[name]) {
      result[name] = {};
    }
    
    result[name][size] = (result[name][size] || 0) + 1;
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(
  groupProducts([
    "camisa-PP", "camisa-M", "camisa-G",
    "camisa-GG", "camisa-GG", "camiseta-PP",
    "camiseta-G", "cueca-M", "blusa-XG",
    "blusa-XG", "blusa-XG", "blusa-P"
  ])
);
```

Basicamente, cada elemento do array original é sempre uma string como `"camisa-PP"`. Separando-a pelo hífen (`-`), obtemos o nome do produto e o respectivo tamanho. Isso é feito em cada iteração do laço de repetição.

Em posse dessas informações, criamos um objeto para cada produto e um sub objeto para cada tamanho. Utilizamos o operador `||`, ali fazendo [avaliação de curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274110/69296), para criar o valor inicial padrão zero, no caso do tamanho ainda não tiver sido contabilizado.

Se você não entendeu nada do código acima, dê um passo para trás e **[entenda como trabalhar com objetos em JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos)**. Enfatize seus estudos desde o básico antes de tentar fazer algo assim, que exige um certo domínio da linguagem e seus mecanismos.

---

Também tem outra formas de fazer isso. Utilizar o [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), por exemplo, é uma outra ideia, mas no fundo a lógica sempre será a mesma.

Comment: Muito obrigado Luiz, de fato sou novo na linguagem, eu até tinha uma ideia de como resolver mas não sabia como utilizar as ferramentas da linguagem. Consegui comprender perfeitamente o código, muito obrigado inclusive pela explicação.